# Tensorflow practice y = xw how do you initialize vector x?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am studying with first machine-learning practice.

This is the prediction system of monthly temperature.

`train_t` has the temperatures and `train_x` has the weight for each data.

However I have a question where initializing `train_x`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pprint import pprint 

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,5])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,1]))

y = tf.matmul(x,w)
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y-t))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

train_t = np.array([5.2,5.7,8.6,14.9,18.2,20.4,25.5,26.4,22.8,17.5,11.1,6.6]) #montly temperature
train_t = train_t.reshape([12,1])
train_x = np.zeros([12,5])

for row, month in enumerate(range(1,13)):
    for col, n in enumerate(range(0,5)):
        train_x[row][col] = month**n ## why initialize like this??


i = 0
for _ in range(10000):
    i += 1
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:train_x,t:train_t})
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        loss_val = sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x:train_x,t:train_t})
        print('step : %d,Loss: %f' % (i,loss_val))
        w_val = sess.run(w)
        pprint(w_val)

def predict(x):
    result = 0.0
    for n in range(0,5):
        result += w_val[n][0] * x**n
    return result

fig = plt.figure()
subplot = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
subplot.set_xlim(1,12)
subplot.scatter(range(1,13),train_t)
linex = np.linspace(1,12,100)
liney = predict(linex)
subplot.plot(linex, liney)
```

However I don't understand here

```
for row, month in enumerate(range(1,13)): #
    for col, n in enumerate(range(0,5)): #
        train_x[row][col] = month**n  ## why initialize like this??
```

What does this mean??
There is no comment about this in my book??
Why train_x is initialized here??

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this bloc of code:

```
train_t = np.array([5.2,5.7,8.6,14.9,18.2,20.4,25.5,26.4,22.8,17.5,11.1,6.6]) #montly temperature
train_t = train_t.reshape([12,1])
train_x = np.zeros([12,5])

for row, month in enumerate(range(1,13)):
    for col, n in enumerate(range(0,5)):
        train_x[row][col] = month**n
```

Is the generation of your data. It initialize `train_t` and `train_x` which are the data that will be injected into `placeholders` `x` and `t`

`train_t` is a tensor of temperatures
`train_x` is a tensor of sort of weight of each temperatures.
They constitute the dataset.

Comment: I don't think that `train_x` is a tensor of weights, since it is a placeholder and it won't be updated during the training, but rather corresponds to the train data. The weights of the model are the ones initialized as `tf.Variable`, which is `w` in this case.

Comment: `train_x` is not a placeholder... `train_x` is the second feature of the dataset which represents kind of the weights of each temperature @PietroTortella

Comment: you are right, `train_x` is not a placeholder. The placeholder of the model are `x` and `t`, while `train_x` and `train_t` are `numpy.array` that you feed to the placeholder. As such, they will not be trained so I think it is incorrect to consider them as parameters of the model. Usually (and I think also in this case), the parameters of the model are the ones initiated as `tf.Variable`, since when executing the `sess.run(train_step)` the `tf.Variable` of the model are updated.

Comment: @PietroTortella Maybe you should read again my answer. It is 100% what I'm saying.

Comment: I find the sentence "train_x is a tensor of sort of weight " misleading...  but you are right, reading more carefully it is correct, sorry for the mess :)

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to explain it. It's obviously a feature but who knows what.

Answer (score 0):

Both `train_x` and `train_t` are arrays with your training data. In the array `train_t` you have the target of your model, while `train_x` contains the features in input to your model.

The weights of your model (the ones that are trained) are `w` (which is the only `tf.Variable` in your code), which is initialized randomly.

The model you are training is a degree 4 (which is the max of `range(0, 5)`) polynomial on the linear variable `month` which ranges in `range(1, 13)`. That snipped of code generates the features for a degree 4 polynomial starting from the linear variable `month`.